# SpringBoot & Kotlin executable jar ClassNotFoundException

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jar, executable-jar, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have an springboot application with kotlin when I run application on ide there is no problem but when I try to run with java-jar the jar file it throws "main" ClassNotFoundException

I also tried main class with Java but didnt work getting same error

I also add start class in properties

```
<start-class>xxx.yyy.ServiceApplication</start-class>
```

And also in plugins, pom file in below

```
<groupId>xxx.yyy.zzz</groupId>
<artifactId>service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>



<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <start-class>xxx.yyy.zzz.service.ServiceApplication</start-class>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <kotlin.version>1.3.11</kotlin.version>
    <org.mapstruct.version>1.3.0.Beta1</org.mapstruct.version>
    <retrofit.version>2.3.0</retrofit.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
        <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
        <version>${retrofit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
        <artifactId>converter-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${retrofit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
        <artifactId>adapter-rxjava2</artifactId>
        <version>${retrofit.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okio/okio -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
        <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId> <!-- use mapstruct-jdk8 for Java 8 or higher -->
        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>

    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.12</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <plugin>spring</plugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
                <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source> <!-- or higher, depending on your project -->
                <target>${java.version}</target> <!-- or higher, depending on your project -->
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <compilerArg>
                        -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                    </compilerArg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <!-- Replacing default-compile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <!-- Replacing default-testCompile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>
</build>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually provide a main method in your Class? It would help to post some code of yours here to identify the problem.

Comment: Hi I added pom file